# How to scrape zip files into a single dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, web, web-scraping

I am very new to web scrapping and I am trying to understand how I can scrape all the zip files and regular files that are on [this website](https://www.omie.es/en/file-access-list?parents%5B0%5D=/&parents%5B1%5D=Day-ahead%20Market&parents%5B2%5D=1.%20Prices&dir=%20Day-ahead%20market%20hourly%20prices%20in%20Spain&realdir=marginalpdbc). The end goal is the scrape all the data, I was originally thinking I could use pd.read_html and feed in a list of each link and loop through each zip file.

I am very new to web scraping so any help at all would be very useful, I have tried a few examples this far please see the below code

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_html("https://www.omie.es/en/file-access-list?parents%5B0%5D=/&parents%5B1%5D=Day-ahead%20Market&parents%5B2%5D=1.%20Prices&dir=%20Day-ahead%20market%20hourly%20prices%20in%20Spain&realdir=marginalpdbc",match="marginalpdbc_2017.zip")
```

So this is what I would like the output to look like except each zip file would need to be its own data frame to work with/loop through. Currently, all it seems to be doing is downloading all the names of the zip files, not the actual data.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open a zipfile and read the files there to a dataframe you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile

zip_url = "https://www.omie.es/es/file-download?parents%5B0%5D=marginalpdbc&filename=marginalpdbc_2017.zip"

dfs = []
with ZipFile(BytesIO(requests.get(zip_url).content)) as zf:
    for file in zf.namelist():
        df = pd.read_csv(
            zf.open(file),
            sep=";",
            skiprows=1,
            skipfooter=1,
            engine="python",
            header=None,
        )
        dfs.append(df)

final_df = pd.concat(dfs)

# print first 10 rows:
print(final_df.head(10).to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 58.82 | 58.82 | nan |
| 2017 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 58.23 | 58.23 | nan |
| 2017 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 51.95 | 51.95 | nan |
| 2017 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 47.27 | 47.27 | nan |
| 2017 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 46.9 | 45.49 | nan |
| 2017 | 1 | 1 | 6 | 46.6 | 44.5 | nan |
| 2017 | 1 | 1 | 7 | 46.25 | 44.5 | nan |
| 2017 | 1 | 1 | 8 | 46.1 | 44.72 | nan |
| 2017 | 1 | 1 | 9 | 46.1 | 44.22 | nan |
| 2017 | 1 | 1 | 10 | 45.13 | 45.13 | nan |

Comment: Thank you, one side question I get this error when running it...

SSLError:
 HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.omie.es', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /es/file-download?parents%5B0%5D=marginalpdbc&filename=marginalpdbc_2017.zip (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))

When I add verify=false it will run but give me a warning. Any reason why this works for you but not me?

Comment: @ARE What operating system do you use? Probably you don't have right certificates installed in your system. (I use Ubuntu 20.04 and don't have error)

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with Ubuntu I am on windows and I am using Spyder as my IDE maybe that is why?

Comment: @ARE You can inspect the certificate of `https://www.omie.es` and then check if you have corresponding certificate authority (CA) installed on your system. Maybe Windows doesn't come with it (?) - that I don't know.